# HBase code cannot successfully run in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase, pom.xml

I tried to run an HBase code in Intellij and set the configuration by Maven. At the final step of the code, results are inserted into the HBase tables I've created before. I checked the Hadoop/HBase version in the terminal, the Hadoop version is 2.9.0 and the HBase version is 1.2.6. Therefore, I set dependencies in the `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I got the error message listed as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getInputStream(Ljava/net/Socket;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:723)
```

Comment: You could check is your hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar is in your local repository.

Comment: There is no version 1.2.6 of [hbase-map-reproduce](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce) in Maven. First version is 2.0.0. The entry in pom.xml is incorrect, it will not built in ordinary maven, however IntelliJ often ignores such errors and builds the project anyway (that's why I do not like IntelliJ).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've checked the jar file and it's there, the version of hbase-map-reduce is also changed. It's still not working.

Comment: I checked the compatibility matrix of Hadoop and HBase and found that Hadoop 2.9.0 is not supported by all versions of HBase. However, the program still does not work after I change the version of Hadoop to 2.7.1

Comment: You have too many overlapping dependencies... You should only need Hadoop and Hbase clients. Plus my answer in the last question of your should work for the versions... Please, please use the properties section of the POM

Answer (score 0):

> the program still does not work after I change the version of Hadoop to 2.7.1

You're going to have to be more clear, but hadoop core also needs to be 2.7

But as pointed out, Hbase mapreduce library that you're using doesn't exist for version 1.2.6

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce

If anything, you want only these to communicate with an Hbase cluster from code. You don't need the Hbase server packages

```
hbase-common 
hbase-client
hbase-hadoop2-compat
```